# Docker container dies & gives: -bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: linux, docker, node.js, memory-management, memory-leaks

Unsure whether tho ask this on here or other communities *(i.e SuperUser or Unix&Linux)* but will keep here for now.

I have a dockerised NodeJS app using Selenium & managed by PM2 runtime. The app runs on the DO box with **1GB** Memory & **25GB** Disk. The app is just to periodically scrape data from a website on an interval of 2 minutes using Selenium WebDriver. I came across this issue a while ago where if I SSH'd into the box, any command spits back:

> -bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable

Setup a new DO box with monitoring to measure the memory usage. My usage was creeping up so thought I had a memory leak somewhere. Tried to find it but couldn't *(still searching)*. I saw that PM2 has an [option](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/memory-limit/) to restart the app if the memory usage gets to a certain point. As a precaution, I set this to `800M` *(80%)*. My `ecosystem.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'scraper',
            script: './index.js',
            watch: process.env.NODE !== 'production',
            ignore_watch: ['node_modules', 'logs', 'test', 'scripts', '.vscode', '.git'],
            out_file: './logs/app.log',
            max_memory_restart: '800M',
            node_args: '--expose-gc',
            env_development: {
                NODE_ENV: 'development'
            },
            env_production: {
                NODE_ENV: 'production'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Having looked around a bit more, I saw that [PM2 can cause a memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522163/node-js-memory-leak-with-pm2) by not running garbage collection thoroughly so I included the node args `--expose-gc` to forcibly run garbage collection on an interval of a minute *(based on [this example](https://www.alexkras.com/simple-guide-to-finding-a-javascript-memory-leak-in-node-js/))*:

```
exports.generateHeapDumpAndStats = function() {
    try {
        if (global.gc) {
            global.gc()
        } else {
            logger.info('Garbage collection unavailable. Use "--expose-gc" when launching to enable forced garbage collection')
        }
        const heapUsed = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed
        const heapUsedMb = (heapUsed / 1024 * 1024).toFixed(2)
        logger.info(`Program is using ${heapUsedMb} MB of heap`)
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error(`Error: ${err.message}`)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}
```

I thought this would be find as even if the garbage collection fails, PM2 would restart @ 80% usage. I started the container @ roughly **10:45pm** *(GMT +1)* & judging from my usage graph, the container cut out @ **2:00am**. This are my usage graphs for the last 24 hours:

[image]

You can see that the memory usage is not even getting near 80% so should I lower my restart threshold as a temporary measure?

I tried to see the memory usage on the box itself but any command I type spits out the error above.

Is it worth me trying to set `--max_old_space_size`? I've seen that a NodeJS process tries to allocate itself 1.5GB of memory which I don't have on this box.

I am very confused as to why this is happening. Sadly, the logs of the container are only written to a local file on the box so I cannot access them now.

I attempted to check the running containers & it spit back something useful once:

[image]

My `npm start` command is:

> *sudo -E pm2-runtime --raw ecosystem.config.js --env production --only scraper*

And complete `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN sudo apt-get install -y nodejs build-essential firefox

# copy package.json & package-lock.json and install packages
# we do this separate from the application code to better use docker's caching
# `npm install` will be cached on future builds if only the app code changed
COPY package*.json ./

RUN sudo npm install pm2 -g
RUN sudo npm install

# ENV vars dynamically set here by CI

# copy the app
COPY . .

# expose port for express & start
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

I'll provide code on request if needed, just didn't think it was initially necessary & didn't want to make the question too large :)

**NOTE:** *I initially posted this question on SO but was requested to 
move it here*

**EDIT**

As per @dirkt 's comment, it looks like I might be hitting a resource limit. `ulimit -a` returns me:

```bsh
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 3842
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 3842
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

So the user has process limits which is what I think is what I'm hitting. However, I'm not entirely sure on where to alter this value & do I set it to `unlimited` or just raise it to an arbitrary value? There are no limits set in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. I've seen a few ways to alter the soft/hard *(`ulimit` CLI, `limits.conf`, `user.conf` - I imagine the latter is irrelevant to me as I am running as `root`)* limits for a user. It is also worth noting that I am running this docker container as `root` *(will change that in future)*

Comment: It's probably not running out of memory, but of some other resource (e.g. max number of processes), in particular if there's a `ulimit` in effect. See e.g. [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205016/fork-retry-resource-temporarily-unavailable) question.

Comment: @dirkt I have edited my question with resource limits I have (not) found. If you provide an answer on how best to proceed with (un)setting the process limits then I'll be happy to accept

Comment: Hey @wmash facing exactly the same issue running "ps -ef | grep -i defunct" shows many zombie chrome processes. Please do share the solution if you found it.